# How to Do Visual Testing (Image Comparison) with Playwright and Cucumber

Tags: playwright

expect(page).toHaveScreenshot()   or expect(value).toMatchSnapshot(snapshotName) is only compatible with playwright test runner. When i am using thsi with (Given,When,Then) stepdefinitions i am getting below error
Error: toMatchSnapshot() must be called during the test
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O6PU.png)

I have tried other library such as getcomparator.But No luck

Comment: In order for someone to help you will need to post a code example of exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Please share an minimal reproducible code example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example